# Syntax error in SQL update

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am new to both MS Access and SQL. Now I am trying to create an inventory database for our company in Ms Access. I try to extract data from the reception form to update the inventory balance. But I met a syntax error message when I executed a SQL `update` statement. This is weird for me because I used the same statements that successfully running in other tables. The only difference is my former successful update working by direct text replacement and my error occurring update is working in a numeric object.

Please help me to check where I am wrong.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Command96_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_Current_Stock" & _
                  "SET Stock_Level= Stock_Level + " & Me!txtOrderQty & "" & _
                  "Where tbl_Current_Stock.Raw_Material= " & Me!cboPurchase.Column(1) & ""
 End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are those underscores really in your code?  Anyway, I don't see a space between the `UPDATE` and `SET` statements.

Comment: Underscores in Visual Basic mean to continue the current line on the next line.

Comment: Please read: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570) and [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friend, follow some tips to generate your updade correctly:

- Check the spaces after concatenating your query
- Be careful not to generate queries with keywords stuck together

> UPDATE **tableTestSET** nome = 'My Name' WHERE active IS NOT NULL **(wrong)**

```
UPDATE tableTest SET name = 'My Name' WHERE active IS NOT NULL
```

- Do not forget to use quotation marks when using strings

> UPDATE tableTest SET **name = My Name** WHERE active IS NOT NULL **(wrong)**

```
UPDATE tableTest SET name = 'My Name' WHERE active IS NOT NULL
```

I hope it helps...

Good Luck!

Comment: As pointed out by maulic and Robert, some space missed. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add spaces before `SET` and `Where`. Otherwise, your command will look something like `UPDATE tbl_Current_stockSET Stock_Level= Stock_Level + 3Where....`.

```
Private Sub Command96_Click()
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_Current_Stock" & " " & _
              "SET Stock_Level= Stock_Level + " & Me!txtOrderQty & " " & _
              "Where tbl_Current_Stock.Raw_Material= " & Me!cboPurchase.Column(1) & ""
End Sub
```

You might also need to wrap the `Raw_Material` column in quotes if it is not numeric.

Comment: Thank you Robert. In my case Raw_Material is a lookup column. By the way, I am writing the sql statement one clause one line. And I wrote the code in office word. How could you find a space is missing in my codes. Could you please recommend me some good sql code editor?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

check your sentence correctly. there is no technical error. there are some space missing in you query.

just add white space before "SET" and "where" words.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tbl_Current_Stock" & _
              " SET Stock_Level= Stock_Level + " & Me!txtOrderQty & "" & _
              " Where tbl_Current_Stock.Raw_Material= " &     Me!cboPurchase.Column(1) & ""
```

Comment: Just as you mentioned I put the statments withion on sentence and it works! Thank you very much for your correction.